# How to solve automatic word change of Text in Flutter Stack?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a Text Widget which automatically changes its sizing when on stack animation. How can I resolve it to stay the same?

[image: Preview]

Comment: Try FittedBox. It scales the contents in similar way images are scaled using boxfit. Check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue?

Comment: i suggest try put the **text** as child of `Flexible` Widget.